# Pronunciation of 'mama' in American English with æ

Tags: pronunciation

I recently heard two instances in recorded music where the word "mama" was pronounced with the first "a" the same as in "cat". Is this at all common, and is it a regional dialect?

The songs are "Statesboro Blues" by the Allman Brothers Band and "Funky Mama Moose" by Roland Haynes.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezPZxfS1jys

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oERBjnrNhWI

Comment: When used with the "cat" vowel, it usually means grandma, or it sometimes is used as a sort of honorific for any matriarch. In *statesboro blues*, we learn that the singer's mom and dad are gone, and that "Well, I looked over in the corner, and Grandpa seemed to have them too."

Comment: Note that pronunciation in singing can be very different from ones usual dialect, and, like any poetry, altered out of any dialect to fit the rhyme and meter scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Allman Brothers tune, to my ears the first "mama" starts as one would expect, but Gregg tenses his voice for effect, essentially fronting the vowel. The second "mama" really does sound like *cat* (TRAP vowel) but likely would be perceived by the audience as the same sort of affect.

This kind of funky jazz/blues always lives, for white performers, somewhere between Coastal South and African American Vernacular. No dialect group in the South, however says "mama" or "momma" with the TRAP vowel, but like PALM, some speakers, both black and white,with a glide on the first syllable. But jazz and blues singers do a lot of bendy things with vowels, so chalk it up to that.

The TRAP-vowel is reserved in the South for one of many pet/babytalk names for grandparents: *mamaw* and *papaw*, vowels like "catpaw," but only if COT and CAUGHT aren't pronounced the same for you.

Gregg Allman's [natural accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCmDhNlAbjA) was a [Coastal South](https://www.google.de/search?q=american%20dialect%20map&rlz=1C9BKJA_enDE701DE701&oq=american%20dialect%20map&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.11685j0j8&hl=de&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=1o2OllG90d7ZeM:) base with lots of Inland/Mountain South features (think Dolly Partin or Willy Nelson).

As for Funky Mama Moose, the effectiveness of the lyrics depends on an effect called [semantic satiation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation), where something is repeated — in this case an already nonsensical funky momma moose — until it becomes mere sound and rhythm. Pronouncing the first syllable of *mama* with the TRAP vowel hastens this effect.

Rest assured that neither of these artists called their mothers anything like Mama Moose.

Comment: on Mama Moose ... don't be so sure! lol

Comment: @lbf: if you call her Mama Moose, just make sure you can outrun her.